# Bash substring separated by spaces

Tags: bash

I've a string like this

```
var="--env=test --arg=foo"
```

I've tried to use substring `${var#*=}` to get for example `test` but don't find a way to separate spaces. Any idea or should I use `cut`?

Comment: You shouldn't have such a string in the first place. It indicates a design flaw. How did you get it? If it's defined in the script, you should rewrite it to use an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array:

```
$ var="--env=test --arg=foo"
$ arr=($var)
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
--env=test
--arg=foo
```

where tokens in `var` are split by `IFS` (which defaults to: space, tab, newline). If you want to split *only* by space, just set `IFS=' '`:

```
IFS=' ' arr=($var)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use BASH regex:

```
var="--env=test --arg=foo"
[[ $var =~ =([^ ]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

test
```

---

Using `extglob`, you can do this in even shorter code:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo "${var//+( *|+([! ])=)}"
test
```

Comment: This is the only solution that avoids splitting and globbing.

Answer (score 1):

`util-linux` (which should be part of any Linux distribution) has *built in* support for  [getopts](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-getopts) command line parsing.

Usage in your case:

```
var="blub --env=test --arg=foo"

eval set -- $(getopt --longoptions env:,arg: -- $var)
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        --arg)
        echo "Arg is $2"
        shift 2
            ;;
        --env)
        echo "Env is $2"
        shift 2
        ;;
        --) shift ; break ;;
    esac
done
```